# How do I change the font used by my vs code editor?

Tags: html, editor, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I'm currently watching a video course on Angular2 development, and suddenly I see this:

[image: Cursive-like font in VS Code]

I know, I know. Pretty HTML attributes are not going to make me a better programmer. But I want this. I need this. I love spicing/personalize my code editors.

The question is: ***What Visual Studio Code extension lets you get formatted HTML attributes like the ones in the picture above?***

Bonus points for recommendations for other extensions that can enhance the look of vs code :) I already got the vscode icons extension.

Comment: Why on earth would anyone ever want this?!

Comment: Mostly just for fun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Iris theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hoisel.theme-iris). It has similar font.

[image]

You can refer to themes creation to make your own theme.

Comment: Ahhh, its a theme that ads the font styles. Nice! Thanks for the answer.